# Dialogflow IP Address

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am currently trying to integrate Dialogflow Bot to an inhouse application. The bot communicates to a database running on a VM. Everthing works fine when I allow all connections to the DB port at the firewall level or when I open a particular IP. Looks like the request from Dialogflow is coming from multiple IP's. Is there a way to know the url or the range of ip's from Dialogflow where requests are sent?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Dialogflow uses many IP addresses, so  it's not enough to "open a particular IP".

As a possible workaround, you can find Google Public IP addresses at the documentation article [IP addresses for default domains](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#ip-addr-defaults) and use them to create firewall rules:

> - Google publishes the complete list of IP ranges that it announces to the internet in [goog.json](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json).
> - Google also publishes a list of Google Cloud customer-usable global and regional external IP addresses ranges in [cloud.json](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json).
>
> The IP addresses used by the default domains for Google APIs and
> services fit within the list of ranges computed by taking away all
> ranges in `cloud.json` from those in `goog.json`.

Answer (score 0):

The data comes from multiple IP as Dataflow uses many VMs. All Dataflow workers have the tag "dataflow" which is what you can use to filter the VMs in the firewawll rule.